# Object.prototype.__proto__ is not null

Tags: javascript

Why is it possible to change Object.prototype.**proto** from null.

Object.prototype is one of the rare objects that has no prototype, and it is not inheriting any properties (according to Flanagan)

I cant imagine how to use Object.prototype.**proto** in real life. 
Please give me an example why is it necessary to change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cant imagine how to use `Object.prototype.__proto__` in real life

You wouldn't use it on `Object.prototype` itself. `__proto__` is an *accessor property* inherited by all objects that inherit from `Object.prototype`. You can use it to get, or even change, *their* prototype (but shouldn't, keep reading). E.g.:

```js
class X {
}
let o = {};
console.log(o.__proto__ === Object.prototype); // true
o.__proto__ = X.prototype;
console.log(o instanceof X);                   // true
console.log(o.__proto__ === Object.prototype); // false
```

It's provided primarily to offer compatibility with existing code on the web that used a proprietary extension to JavaScript in Mozilla's JavaScript engines. Instead of using `o.__proto__`, use `Object.getPrototypeOf(o)` and `Object.setPrototypeOf(o, ...)`. (In fact, officially JavaScript engines aren't supposed to have `__proto__` at all except when they're being used in web browsers. [It's defined in](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object.prototype.__proto__) an *annex* to the spec, not the spec itself, which only applies to web browser JavaScript engines.)

An in general, don't even use `Object.setPrototypeOf`. Changing the prototype of an object after it's been constructed is almost always indicative of a design problem. (And makes subsequent operations on the object very slow [in relative terms].)

Comment: Informative. I thought that __proto__ is a property that is not inherited but overriden.

Comment: @sgko: Yeah, the definition is effectively `get __proto__() { return Object.getPrototypeOf(Object(this)); }  set __proto__(p) { Object.setPrototypeOf((Object(this), Object(p)); }` (there's a bit of hand-waving in there, but that's basically it). This is also why if you do `let o = Object.create(null);`, `o` has no `__proto__` (because it doesn't inherit from `Object.prototype`). That's true even if it has a prototype, e.g. `let o2 = Object.create(o);` creates an `o2` with no `__proto__` but which does have a prototype (`o`). (I hope that isn't as unclear as I fear it may be...)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a whole page about Object.prototype.**proto** [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) note that it is used as a getter and setter method to expose the prototype of an object and that it has been deprecated in favor Object.getPrototypeOf and Object.setPrototypeOf. It has plenty of uses when you want to change the properties of an Objects prototype.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it possible to change `Object.prototype.__proto__` from `null`?

Well, it is not possible. Try it yourself in any modern browser:

```
> Object.setPrototypeOf(Object.prototype, Object.create(null))
Uncaught TypeError: Immutable prototype object '#<Object>' cannot have their prototype set
```

These [immutable prototype exotic objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-immutable-prototype-exotic-objects) were introduced with ES7.